# jQuery Pop- out browser is not calling on href link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

***functionality:***

User clicks on the link in page A, it will prompt a pop-up. The pop-up is displaying separate web-browser thread which is an overlay over the page A which will turn opaque.

***What has been done:***

This is the code that has been done to enable to pop-up web browser:

```js
$('link1').click(function() {
      $('#subscribe-pop1’).toggle();
 
 });
```

```html
<div id="footleft">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" id='link1'>India, Mumbai</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" id='link2'>India, New Delhi</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" id='link3'>India, Chennai and Banglalore</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" id='link4'>United Arab Emirates, Dubai</a> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div id="subscribe-pop1" style="display:none">
  <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com/js/">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

***Issue:***

When I try to click on the link, it will only work for some of the url links. It will work if the url link is "http://www.w3schools.com/js/" but it may not work  for "http://www.youtube.com".

It will only display a white screen for url that is not called.

I would like to know why is that so that the following href is only able to call on some url but not the rest and how am I able to rectify this issue?? thanks

Comment: That is because certain webpages can't be framed, they use a [special header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) to make sure that you visit the page directly, not in an iframe

Comment: @adeneo is there anyway for me to bypass this so that it can still be contained in an iframe?

Comment: No, then sites like Google and Youtube wouldn't be using the `X-Frame-Options` header, the entire point is to avoid being framed

Comment: @adeneo so the only way is to have a spin-off browser with the full header?? like a normal browser page?

Comment: There is no "spin-off" browser, the sites you're trying to load in an iframe sets the special [**X-Frame-Options**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) header, which makes it impossible to load that webpage in an iFrame. The only viable workaround is to get the content on your own server, and then send that clientside, but that won't get you dynamic content etc. and sites like Google makes it hard to do that as well, because they want people to visit and link to their page, not frame it.

Comment: @adeneo, alright..ok!thanks